# What is the most common used Pi OS

Tags: raspbian

im new to the Pi and im setting mine up and it gives a list of the OS's to install but i have no idea which but it recommends the Raspbian full with desktop so assume that would be the one to go with? im looking of rone with the most users and possible help or tips using it, Thanks

Comment: You can go with Raspbian buster head or headless!

Comment: There is a lot of OS and distribution which you can choose to use according to your objective of using Raspberry Pi. Do you want to use it as a normal desktop or something more?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Raspbian (Buster) with Desktop is the most common OS. It is recommended and maintained by the Raspberry Pi foundation.

I assume your installing with Noobs, if you get problems you can download Raspbian with Desktop and flash direct to sd card using Etcher.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: ...and will likely be the best supported by other users if you have problems.

Comment: OK thanks thats what i figured and installed and yes i formatted the SD then loaded the NOOBS software and im going threw the install now just waiting for the blue bar to creep across we will see how it goes

Comment: If NOOBs doesn't work out just try straight Raspbian; despite the name and the Foundation pushing it (and judging by many posts here over the years), NOOBS probably just adds a layer of confusion and not convenience.